# Blocking in Netty 4

Tags: java, sockets, netty

Is there any way for run some code in blocking mode in Netty 4 client? I can't find any issue or example of how I can run some code in blocking mode. My problem is creating a user login system and I must get success or error from server rigth away after the request and dependency of response do another work in client side. I don't believe that such a powerful tool can't do it

P.S. sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a blocking netty, what you need is to send data with netty client in the netty way, then waits on a SettableFuture object that will be set in the netty inbound handler.  So it's your program that is blocking, not netty's.